# Where is the manpage of endsgent?

Tags: manpage, shadow

https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/gshadow/gshadow.h.html

I don't find the manpage of `endsgent`. Does anybody know which package has the manpage for `endsgent`?

Comment: Which distro and version of LInux are you using? How did you install endsgent?

Comment: There is no manpage for endsgent.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/missing_pages.html

Comment: See https://sources.debian.org/src/gnulib/20210102%7Eebaa53c-1/doc/glibc-functions/endsgent.texi/?hl=2#L2 .